# The Inverse of sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Assume to have a Positive Semi Definite matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, defined as

$$A = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i x_i^\top = \sum_{i=1}^n A_i$$

such that $\alpha_i \in [0,1]: \sum_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i = 1$, $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $n>d$.

Further, assume that $A$ is a singular matrix, that is equivalent to the condition $\lambda_{min}(A) = 0$.

It is known that $\lambda_{min}(A) \geq \sum_{i = 1}^n\lambda_{min}(A_i)$, thus even when all matrices $A_i$ are singular, $A$ can be invertible.

A trivial example for $n = 2$ would be
$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, $A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, that are singular but whose sum is non-singular.

**What are the necessary (and possibly sufficient) conditions on the matrices $A_i$ and on the vectors $x_i$ under which $A$ is singular?**

Comment: I imagine $\mathrm{span} \{x_1,\dots, x_n\} = \mathbb{R}^d$ should be necessary and sufficient.

Comment: $A$ is singular iff one of the $\alpha_i$ is zero or the $x_i$ fail to be linearly independent.

Comment: @BenGrossmann can you explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $i_1,\dots,i_k$ denote the values of $i$ for which $a_{i} \neq 0$.
Let $D$ denote the diagonal matrix
$$
D = \pmatrix{a_{i_1} \\ & \ddots \\ && a_{i_k}}.
$$
Your matrix can be written as $A = XDX^T$, where $X$ is the matrix with columns $x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_k}$.

The rank of this matrix is necessarily equal to the rank of $X$. In particular, $X$ has the same rank as $M = XD^{1/2}$, and $M$ necessarily has the same rank as $A = MM^T$. Thus, $A$ is singular if and only if the columns of $X$ fail to span $\Bbb R^d$, which occurs iff the rows of $X$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @BenGrossmann. Since $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ it is not a product of square matrices. Does this change the result?

Comment: Yes it does, I had missed that. I'll change my answer accordingly

Comment: @Apprentice see my latest edit.